# Substring under PropertyGroup in msbuild props not working when property is passed as argument to msbuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, vsprops

In my props file, i pass the `BUILD_VERSION` to `dotnet msbuild` using properties as `/p:BUILD_VERSION=1.2.3.4`. However, i get errors on when performing `Substring` operation on property `BuildVersion` which gets its value from : `BUILD_VERSION`.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>./obj/</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <BuildVersion>$(BUILD_VERSION)</BuildVersion>
    <InformationalVersion>$(BuildVersion)</InformationalVersion>
    <BuildMajorVersion>$([System.String]::Concat($(BuildVersion.Substring(0, $(BuildVersion.IndexOf('.')))), ".0.0.0"))</BuildMajorVersion>
    <AssemblyVersion>$(BuildMajorVersion)</AssemblyVersion>
    <AssemblyFileVersion>$(BuildMajorVersion)</AssemblyFileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The error that i get is : `""".Substring(0,-1)" length should be inside the string`

I checked that `BUILD_VERSION` is present by printing in it in `Message`.

```
  <Target Name="SetBuildVersions" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="BUILD_VERSION=$(BUILD_VERSION)"/>
  </Target>
```

It prints `BUILD_VERSION=1.2.3.4`.

If i hardcode `<BuildVersion>1.2.3.4</BuildVersion>` instead of `<BuildVersion>$(BUILD_VERSION)</BuildVersion>` below, it works.

If i use the `Substring` code inside a `Target` it works :

```
  <Target Name="SetBuildVersions" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <InformationalVersion>$(BuildVersion)</InformationalVersion>
      <BuildMajorVersionOnly>$([System.String]::Concat($(BuildVersion.Substring(0, $(BuildVersion.IndexOf('.')))), ".0.0.0"))</BuildMajorVersionOnly>
      <AssemblyVersion>$(BuildMajorVersionOnly)</AssemblyVersion>
      <AssemblyFileVersion>$(BuildMajorVersionOnly)</AssemblyFileVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```

Why can't i use the `Substring` inside normal `PropertyGroup` when passing `BUILD_VERSION` as property argument to `msbuild` ?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this with a variety of `dotnet` SDK versions (1.0.0 upwards) and only see this message when not passing the property via command line to any of the `dotnet` commands (`restore`,`build`,`publish`) etc. Can you create an isolated sample project or add a binary log created by appending `/bl` to the command? (creates msbuild.binlog file)

Comment: @MartinUllrich Thanks for telling me about `/bl` I looked at the output in binary view logger and now everything is clear. I am firing a custom `dotnet restore` command from my targets and it does not pass that variable. Do you know of a cleaner way to pass properties forward to a task ? Or how to capture the properties passed to the project ?

Comment: http://msbuildlog.com/ has binary logger viewer.